# CSS works in Chromium, but in Firefox has tons of errors

Tags: css, firefox, chromium

During testing I realized that my webpage is not working seamlessly, there is a little delay and a flashing before loading in **Firefox**, but in **Chromium** it works perfectly. Also, in Firefox after the problematic loading the site looks good. I was looking at **Inspect Element** and found that under Console tab there are a lot of errors and warnings, like eg. these:

> Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped. 
>   style.css:50:22 Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’. 
>   Declaration dropped.  style.css:51:22 Error in parsing value for
>   ‘-webkit-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped.  style.css:53:27
>   Unknown property ‘-moz-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped. 
>   style.css:54:22 Unknown property ‘-moz-box-shadow’.  Declaration
>   dropped.  style.css:58:19 Error in parsing value for
>   ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped.  style.css:90:22 Error in
>   parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped. 
>   style.css:91:22 Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’. 
>   Declaration dropped.  style.css:105:22 Error in parsing value for
>   ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped.  style.css:106:22 Unknown
>   property ‘-moz-box-shadow’.  Declaration dropped.  style.css:109:19
>   Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped. 
>   style.css:131:22 Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’. 
>   Declaration dropped.  style.css:132:22 Unknown property
>   ‘-moz-box-shadow’.  Declaration dropped.  style.css:141:19 Error in
>   parsing value for ‘-webkit-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped. 
>   style.css:143:27 Unknown property ‘-moz-border-radius’.  Declaration
>   dropped.  style.css:144:22 Unknown property ‘-moz-box-shadow’. 
>   Declaration dropped.  style.css:159:19 Error in parsing value for
>   ‘-webkit-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped.  style.css:161:27
>   Unknown property ‘-moz-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped. 
>   style.css:162:22 Unknown property ‘-moz-box-shadow’.  Declaration
>   dropped.  style.css:176:19 Error in parsing value for
>   ‘-webkit-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped.  style.css:178:27
>   Unknown property ‘-moz-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped. 
>   style.css:179:22 Unknown property ‘-moz-box-shadow’.  Declaration
>   dropped.  style.css:193:19 Error in parsing value for
>   ‘-webkit-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped.  style.css:195:27
>   Unknown property ‘-moz-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped. 
>   style.css:196:22 Unknown property ‘-moz-box-shadow’.  Declaration
>   dropped.  style.css:210:19 Error in parsing value for
>   ‘-webkit-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped.  style.css:212:27
>   Unknown property ‘-moz-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped. 
>   style.css:213:22 Unknown property ‘-moz-box-shadow’.  Declaration
>   dropped.  style.css:230:19 Error in parsing value for
>   ‘-webkit-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped.

For instance, here is a part of my CSS, where I got error from (style.css:50:22, line 50 is marked):

```
.menu li {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #ff0000;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000, #00ff00);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000, #00ff00);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000, #00ff00); /* line 50 */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000, #00ff00);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff0000, #00ff00);
    -webkit-border-radius: 4;
    -moz-border-radius: 4;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #222222;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #0a0d01;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #0a0d01;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #0a0d01;
    font-size: 21px;    
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

How can I resolve this?
I am not an expert, please be specific in your answer. Thanks!

UPDATE: I forgot to mention, that yesterday I got this error too (today disappeared, but currently I got it again): **"Style sheet could not be loaded http://fonts.googleapis.com/css>>some fonts here"**

Comment: It's perfectly fine - firefox drops and warns about properties he doesn't support - those that are prefixed for other browsers, for example -webkit-box-shadow, -ms-linear-gradient, etc...

Comment: OK, but the site has something problem during loading.

Comment: Hence the word temporary

Comment: Reduce the noise by **temporarily** removing all properties, which are not general or targeting firefox, and see what happens. When you're done checking, restore the removed properties :)

Comment: Is there anyone who DOES know what causes the problem?

Comment: Can you please provide a jsbin.com/jsfiddle.net that reproduces the issue, so it's easy for us to help you?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know them, am not an expert.